# What is the best way in css to have two left aligned columns where first is fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want two columns where first column is an image and the second column is text.  I want to avoid using html tables if possible.  I want the text of the second column to be aligned left so it will line up against the image and go to the rest of the page width

I see that I can do something like this for the first column:

```
 #left_col {
       float:left;
        width: 650px;
    }
```

but can't figure out the right css for the second (all examples I see on the web have the right column right aligned).  What is the best way in CSS to have two columns where first is fixed and the second column is aligned left (to the right of the picture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like;

```
#image, #text{
    position: absolute;
}
#image {
    top: 0;
    width: 650px;
}
#text {
    top: 0;
    left: 650px;
    right: 0;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/qAa7N/)*** is a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 columns would have exactly the same CSS, where the width is half the total width. This is a basic grid layout, if you want to look further into it :)

Comment: I don't want it to be 1/2 the total width.  I want first col to be fixed and second col to be everything else

Comment: If the first column is fixed, then you should know the width of the second column, yes? Or is it the width of the browser window?

Comment: if that's the case, just get rid of the width - simply float:left, and the div will automatically be the width of the content.

Comment: another option, where the div fills the whole space is to use: margin-left:100px; width:100%

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right...

#### HTML

```
<div id="left_col">
    Content
</div>
<div id="main">
    Content
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
}

#main {
    margin-left: 650px;
}
```

#### DEMO

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REhuK/)

Comment: I want the second column to be the rest of the apge (not fixed at 650 px)

Answer (score 0):

check http://jsfiddle.net/EyKZ7/, leave the second column `width` to default `auto`, it will take the rest of space